# unable to understand the syntax of executesql in python

Tags: python, database

We are using this query to get information from the db :-

```
 name=db.executesql('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_name')[0][0]
```

Any one can please elaborate this. I get same result  when i used or not `[0][0]` at the end of this query. Can somebody help in understanding the use of `[0][0]` in this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `executesql` will return a nested list. `[0][0]` means that the `name` variable will contain the first element inside the first list returned by the query.

Comment: Thanks Gabor Erdos.